# How do I separate parts of an armature, based on which mesh they're attached to?

Tags: mesh, armature, .fbx

I have an FBX file that I imported into Blender 3.0.  This file has multiple meshes, and each mesh has bones attached to it, but they're all collected together as one armature.  I want to separate each of the meshes into individual FBX files, and keep only the relevant bones attached to each mesh.

In Object mode, selecting any bone selects the entire armature.  In Edit mode, I can select individual bones, but changing to Edit mode rearranges the entire armature into a default pose; the bones are then all clustered together, and separating them is not feasible.

What I want to do is to select one mesh, and then also select all bones that affect that mesh, get rid of everything else, and then export just the selection as a new, smaller FBX.  How do I do this?

Comment: Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SrD6MpXP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/SrD6MpXP/)

Comment: Any ideas?  I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: I tried working on a script and was having issues figuring it out. Had to take a break. It kind of works but keeps crashing when I run it. It keeps hanging on the part where I am creating the meshes from pydata, it seems to create them all but just freezes after that point. If you want you can [copy](https://pastebin.com/ttc486Yr) it and take a look, see if you can get any further.

Comment: Thanks, Jake.  I'm afraid that's way over my head.